# Dealing with random failure datatypes in Elasticsearch 2.X

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

So im working on a system that logs bad data sent to an api and what the full request was. Would love to be able to see this in Kibana.

Issue is the datatypes could be random, so when I send them to the bad_data field it fails if it dosen't match the original mapping.

Anyone have a suggestion for the right way to handle this?

(2.X Es is required due to a sub dependancy)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ignore_malformed flag in your field mappings. In that case wrong format values will not be indexed and your document will be saved.
See [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed) for more information.
If you want to be able to query such fields as original text you could use [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/multi-fields.html) in your mapping for multi-type indexing, to get fast queries on raw text values.